# Porting 32 bit C++ code to 64 bit - is it worth it? Why?

Tags: c++, x86, 64-bit, x86-64, cpu-architecture

I am aware of some the obvious gains of the x64 architecture (higher addressable RAM addresses, etc)... but:

- What if my program has no real need to run in native 64 bit mode. Should I port it anyway?
- Are there any foreseeable deadlines for ending 32 bit support?
- Would my application run faster / better / more secure as native x64 code?

Comment: If it's simple to do (Just recompiling your C++ code) do it, it's nice.

Comment: I've ported many applications over to x64 (such as my shell extensions), its the worth thats in question for applications that do not *require* it. For most applications (every one I've ever ported), it is not as simple as just recompiling.

Comment: @NTDLS, what problems specifically did you have with porting to x64? If you run into significant troubles, then it may be that the original design wasn't too good (as in, too many architecture-specific assumptions and/or hacks).

Comment: What operating system? If it's Windows, then many users will not be able to run your app, because most users don't have 64-bit Windows. If it's OS X, then go ahead; today's OS X is a mix of 32-bit and 64-bit already.

Comment: Adding to Jesper: You can expect Apple to drop 32bit support in a few years. New libraries are already 64-bit only.

Comment: I would estimate that decent 32bit support will last until 2025. It likely won't be abandoned until 2038 is getting too close for comfort.

Comment: @Matt assuming other platform, looks like Apple is forcing it earlier if you use their platform.

Answer (score 67, accepted):

x86-64 is a bit of a special case - for many architectures (eg. SPARC), compiling an application for 64 bit mode doesn't give it any benefit unless it can profitably use more than 4GB of memory.  All it does is increase the size of the binary, which can actually make the code *slower* if it impacts on cache behaviour.

However, x86-64 gives you more than just a 64 bit address space and 64 bit integer registers - it also **doubles** the number of general purpose registers, which on a register-deficient architecture like x86 can result in a significant performance increase, with just a recompile.

It also lets the compiler assume that many extensions, like SSE and SSE2, are present, which can also significantly improve code optimisation.

Another benefit is that x86-64 adds PC-relative addressing, which can significantly simplify position-independent code.

However, if the app isn't performance sensitive, then none of this is really important either.

Comment: Strictly speaking, x86-64 doesn't necessarily double the number of real registers.  I believe all the desktop CPUs are doing register renaming in the execution pipeline, so all that x86-64 changes is the number of architecturally visible registers, but not the actual number. Now, this can give the compiler more ability to eliminate load and store ops, so optimizations like code hoisting may be enabled with the extra architectural registers.

Comment: Making those registers visible to the compiler definitely helps it optimize though - in general the more optimisation that can be done at higher layers the better.

Comment: In addition to increasing the size of the binary, it doubles the size of every pointer use, but the performance effect of that could be lumped under "cache behavior" which you did note.

Comment: A great answer, you point out all the important major differences (or lack thereof). I've been raving about the extensions assumption for as long as I've cared to compare the architectures. :)

Comment: Also, x86-64 adds PC-relative addressing, which helps PIC code.

Comment: @ninjalj: Thanks, I've added that to the answer for posterity ;)

Comment: It should also be noted that on Windows systems, when you compile an application into native x64, you no longer run your program virtualized via the WOW64 sub-system anymore - which in itself possesses a performance impact - small or not, it is at least measureable and probably dependent on if your application is CPU or I/O intensive etc.

Answer (score 28):

One possible benefit I haven't seen mentioned yet is that it might uncover latent bugs. Once you port it to 64-bit, a number of changes are made. The sizes of some datatypes change, the calling convention changes, the exception handling mechanism (at least on Windows) changes.

All of this might lead to otherwise hidden bugs surfacing, which means that you can fix them.

Assuming your code is correct and bug-free, porting to 64-bit should in theory be as simple as flicking a compiler switch. If that fails, it is because you're relying on things not guaranteed by the language, and so, they're potential sources of errors.

Comment: Excellent point. Many bugs come up during architecture and compiler switches, among other things.

Comment: Agreed. I compile my code with as many different compilers on as many different platforms as are feasible.  It's amazing what you can find that way.

Comment: Well, this is also a disadvantage: I hope you'll be the one which will catch your own newly raising bugs, otherwise you'll finish in having some security holes!

Answer (score 18):

Here's what 64-bit does for you:

- 64-bit allows you to use more memory than a 32-bit app.
- 64-bit makes all pointers 64-bits, which makes your code footprint larger.
- 64-bit gives you more integer and floating point registers, which causes less spilling registers to memory, which should speed up your app somewhat.
- 64-bit can make 64-bit ALU operations faster (only helpful if you're using 64-bit data types).
- You DO NOT get any extra security (another answer mentioned security, I'm not aware of any benefits like that).
- You're limited to only running on 64-bit operating systems.

I've ported a number of C++ apps and seen about a 10% speedup with 64-bit code (same system, same compiler, the only change was a 32-bit vs 64-bit compiler mode), but most of those apps were doing a fair amount of 64-bit math.  YMMV.

I wouldn't worry about 32-bit support going away any time soon.

(Edited to include notes from comments - thanks!)

Comment: You forgot that a x86 processor provides tons of more registers in 64-bit mode than in 32-bit mode. This allows the compiler to optimize your code to keep more stuff in registers rather than in ram.

Comment: You didn't mention flat segmentation.  If for some reason you *want* to use segmentation, you can't use 64-bit code.

Comment: You can get extra security in 64-bit mode if you're using address space layout randomization.  32-bit address space is small enough that this can sometimes be cracked by brute force.  Not so for 64-bit space.

Comment: You also gets a bit more secure since there are already NX bit in x86_64, which may not present in previous x86 CPUs. Windows 64-bit also requires drivers to be signed, makes it more stable and safer. Besides, 64-bit does not necessarily makes the footprint larger since there are [x32 ABI](https://sites.google.com/site/x32abi/) in which pointers are still 32 bits https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X32_ABI

Answer (score 5):

Although its true that 32-bit will be around for a while in some form or another, Windows Server 2008 R2 ships with a 64-bit SKU only. I would not be surprised to see WOW64 as an install option as early as Windows 8 as more software migrates to 64-bit. WOW64 is a install, memory and performance overhead. The 3.5GB RAM limit in 32-bit Windows along with increasing RAM densities will encourage this migration. I'd rather have more RAM than CPU...

Embrace 64-bit! Take the time to make your 32-bit code 64-bit compatible, its a no brainer and straightforward. For normal applications the changes are more accurately describes as code corrections. For drivers the choice is: adapt or lose users. When the time comes you'll be ready to deploy on any platform with a recompile.

IMO the current cache related issues are moot; silicon improvements in this area and further 64-bit optimisation will be forthcoming.

Comment: You do know that a 32-bit version of Win7 can still run 16-bit apps, yes? So I think it's a bit premature to talk about removal of 32-bit support.

Comment: Why is it premature when Microsoft have already done it in Server 2008 R2? 16-bit support isn't native and 32-bit support doesn't have to be native; Windows 7's XP Mode already points in one possible direction. Being prepared costs very little

Comment: Server operating systems are a special case. Severs need to do a lot of work and will use every resource available to do that work. 64-bit definitely provides a big improvement to performance there.

For general-purpose stuff, 64-bit provides no advantages. Unless there is a specific reason to move to 64-bit, don't do it. It's a terrible waste of time, better spend that time adding features and fixing bugs.

Comment: Also it works like this, 64bit OS supports Wow32, but not Wow16, and 32Bit OS supports Wow16. So if 128bit machines come along then wow32 will likely be kicked to the kerb.

Answer (score 3):

1. If your program has no need to run under 64-bit, why would you? If you are not memory bound, and you don't have huge datasets, there is no point. The new Miata doesn't have bigger tires, because it doesn't NEED them.
2. 32-bit support (even if only via emulation) will extend long past when your software ceases to be useful. We still emulate Atari 2600s, right?
3. No, in all likelyhood, your application will be slower in 64-bit mode, simply because less of it will fit in the processor's cache. It might be slightly more secure, but good coders don't need that crutch :)

Rico Mariani's post on why Microsoft **isn't** porting Visual Studio to 64-bit really sums it up [Visual Studio: Why is there no 64 bit version? (yet)](http://blogs.msdn.com/ricom/archive/2009/06/10/visual-studio-why-is-there-no-64-bit-version.aspx)

Comment: Thanks for the 64Bit Visual Studio link - I had no idea. Very cool post!

Comment: You should be careful lest you cherry-pick some products to support your point. Yes, there's no 64-bit VS2010 (which doesn't mean it won't be considered for some future version), but on the other hand Office 2010 will have a 64-bit version, and that's a far more popular application - and also one with no clear need to be 64-bit.

Comment: @Pavel how else would you load a 5GB Excel spreadsheet? :D 

64-bit VS will come. 3rd party add-ins are surely a/the key obstacle and reasonably so.

Comment: @mctrousers Anyone who is using a 5GB Excel spreadsheet is clearly using the wrong tool for the job. What on earth would you be storing in a spreadsheet which is that large, and wouldn't be better suited to a database? But to answer your question, you would do it by not loading the entire thing into memory all at once.

Answer (score 3):

Unless there's a business reason to go to 64 bit, then there's no real "need" to support 64 bit.

However, there are some good reasons for going to 64 bit at some point, aside from all those that others have already mentioned.

- It's getting harder to buy PCs that aren't 64 bit. Even though 32 bit apps will run in compatibility mode for years to come, any new PCs being sold today or in the future are likely to be 64 bit. If I have a shiny 64 bit operating system I don't really want to run "smelly old 32 bit apps" in compatibility mode!
- Some things just don't run properly in comptibility mode - it's not the same thing as running on a 32-bit OS on 32-bit hardware. I've run into a few issues (e.g. registry access across the 32/64 bit registry hives, programs that fail because they're not in the folder they expect to be in, etc) when running in compatibility mode. I always feel nervous about running my code in compatibility mode - it's simply "not the real thing", and it often shows.
- If you have written your code cleanly, then chances are you only have to recompile it as a 64 bit exe and it'll work fine, so there's no real reason not to give it a try.
- the earlier you build a native 64 bit version, the easier it will be to keep it working on 64 bit as you add new features. That's a much better plan than continuing to develop in the dark ages for another 'n' years and then trying to jump out into the light.
- When you go for your next job interview, you will be able to say that you have 64-bit expeirence and 32->64 porting experience.

Comment: Comptibility mode is one thing as in Vista and Win7 Wow64 emulator; but Windows 7 XP Mode uses an XP VM, which is really the real thing for 99.99% of situations -- much higher than with the Wow64 which I agree has some issues.

Answer (score 2):

It depends on whether your code is an application or a reusable library. For a library, keep in mind that the client of that library may have good reasons to run in 64-bit mode, so you have to ensure that your scenario works. This may also apply to applications when they are extensible via plugins.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't have any real need now, and likely never will, for 64-bit mode, you shouldn't do porting.

If you don't have the need now, but may have it some day, you should try to estimate how much effort it will be (e.g. by turning on all respective compiler warnings, and attempting a 64-bit compilation). Expect that some things aren't trivial, so it will be useful to know how what problems you would likely encounter, and how long it would likely take to fix them.

Notice that a need may also arise from dependencies: if your program is a library (e.g. a DLL), it may be necessary to port it to 64-bit mode just because some host application gets ported.

For a foreseeable future, 32-bit applications will continue to be supported.

Answer (score 1):

You are already aware of the x64 advantages (most importantly the increased RAM size) and you are not interested in any, then don't port an executable (exe). Usually performance degrades after a port, mainly due to the increase in size of a x64 module over x86: all pointers now require double length, and this percolates everywhere, including code size (some jumps, function calls, vtables, virtual invokes, global symbols etc etc). Is not a significant degradation, but is usually measurable (3-5% speed decrease, depends on many factors).

DLLs are worth porting because you gain a new 'audience' in x64 apps that are able to consume your DLL.

Comment: About time sombody mentioned the 'audience'! Seems like alot of consumers look for 64bit apps for their machines.

Answer (score 1):

For example, if you had written 32-bit code (GNU C/++) as below
EDIT: format code

```
struct packet {
    unsigned long name_id;
    unsigned short age;
};
```

for network messaging, then you need to do porting while re-compiling on a 64 bit system, because of htonl/ntohl etc, communication get broken in the case of the network peer is still using the 32 bit system (using the same code as yours); you know sizeof(long) will be changed from 32 to 64 too at your side.

See more notes about 32/64 porting at http://code.google.com/p/effocore/downloads/list, document name EffoCoreRef.pdf.

Comment: i'm using 64 bits system, faster, much more memory; pretty good.

Comment: also you could refer to http://code.google.com/p/effogpled/downloads/list, document named EffoDesign_MemTest.pdf for multi-channel MC and concurrent data bus burst etc on a latest x86_64 platform.

Answer (score 1):

Some OSs or configurations are unable to run 32-bit programs. A minimal Linux without 32-bit [libc](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_standard_library) installed for example. Also IIRC I usually compile out the 32-bit support from the kernel.

If these OSs or configurations are part of your potential user base then yes, you should port it.

If you need more speed, then you should also port it (as others have said, x86-64 has more registers and cool instructions that speed it up).

Or, of course, if you want to mmap() or otherwise map a large file or lots of memory. Then 64-bit helps.

Answer (score 0):

It's pretty unlikely that you'd see any benefit unless you're in need of extreme security measures or obscene amounts of RAM.

Basically, you'd most likely know intuitively if your code was a good candidate for 64-bit porting.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding deadlines. I would not worry, things like 32bit will be around for a good while natively and for a foreseeable future in some other form.

Answer (score 0):

See my answer to this question [here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1283797/processor-os-32bit-64-bit/1303244#1303244) I closed out that post saying that a 64-bit computer can store and retrieve much more information than a 32-bit computer. For most users this really doesn't mean a whole lot because things like browsing the web, checking email and playing Solitaire all work comfortably within the confines of 32-bit addressing. Where the 64-bit benefit will really shine is in areas where you have a lot of data the computer will have to churn through. Digital signal processing, gigapixel photography and advanced 3D gaming are all areas where their massive amounts of data processing would see a big boost in a 64-bit environment.

As for your code running faster/better, it's entirely up to your code and the requirements imposed on it.

Answer (score 0):

As to performance issues, it depends on your program actually. If your program is pointer-intensive, porting to 64-bit may cause performance downgrading, since for CPU cache with the same size, each 64-bit pointer occupy more space on cache, and virtual-to-physical mappings also occupies more TLB space. Otherwise, if your program is not pointer-intensive, its performance will benefit from x64.

Of course performance is not the only reason for porting, other issues like porting effort, time scheduling should also be considered.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend porting it to 64 bit just so you are running "native"  (Also, I use OpenBSD. In their AMD64 port, they do not provide any 32 bit emulation support, everything must be 64 bit)

Also, `stdint.h` is your best friend! By porting your application, you should learn how to code portably. Which will make your code work right when we have 128 bit processors too (in a few decades hopefully)

I've ported 2 or 3 things to 64 bit and now develop for both (which is very easy if you use stdint.h) and on my first project porting to 64 bit caused like 2 or 3 bugs to show up, but that was it. Most of it was a simple recompile and now I don't worry about the differences between 32 and 64 bit when making new code because I just automatically code portably. (using intptr_t and size_t and such)

Answer (score 0):

In the case of a dll being called from a 64 bits process then the dll have to be 64 bits as well.
Then it does not matter if it's worth it, you simply have no choice.

Answer (score 0):

One issue to keep in mind is the software libraries available.  For instance, my company develops an application that uses multiple OpenGL libraries, and we do so on the OpenSuSE OS.  In older versions of the OS, one could download a 32-bit versions of these libraries on the x86_64 architecture.  Newer versions, however, don't have this.  It made it easier to just compile in 64-bit mode.

Answer (score -2):

64 bit will run a lot faster, when 64 bits compilers become mature, but when it will occur I dont know