# Windows 7, Visual Studio 2008 and Qt 4.6, 32 OR 64 bit?

Tags: visual-studio-2008, qt, windows-7, 32bit-64bit

I'm trying to install Windows 7 64bit (as oppose to 32bit), mainly because large amount of RAM would be wasted otherwise.

I wonder if I should install Visual Studio 2008 32bit OR 64bit. I also uses Qt 4.5/4.6 for development, does it play well in 64bit environment?

Any suggestions on what will be a most recommended configuration?

Comment: @lyxera: "mainly because large amount of RAM would be wasted otherwise.". I dont understand your this point.Clarify it further.

Comment: Is there even a 64bit VS2008? I thought VS2010 was the first version to have a 64bit version.

Comment: @Ray: VS2010 will be x86 only AFAIK. See http://news.softpedia.com/news/Don-039-t-Hold-Your-Breath-for-64-bit-Visual-Studio-113943.shtml

Comment: 32bit OS can utilize only 3G of RAM as I understood. So I had to install 64bit OS in order not to waste my 6G RAM.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think [there are any 64-bit versions of Visual Studio](http://blogs.msdn.com/ricom/archive/2009/06/10/visual-studio-why-is-there-no-64-bit-version.aspx) available. This makes answering this question easy: choose 32-bit Visual Studio.

This doesn't prevent you from actually compiling 64-bit applications if you choose (i.e. need) to do so, however. You'll need to compile Qt yourself to generate the 64-bit libraries, but other than that things should be fairly straightforward.

Now, on the other hand, if you don't need to develop 64-bit Windows applications ([you probably don't](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1479953/porting-32-bit-c-code-to-64-bit-is-it-worth-it-why)), you can just use the officially provided compiled 32-bit [Qt libraries for VS2008](http://qt.nokia.com/downloads/windows-cpp-vs2008) and save yourself multiple hours building Qt. I've experienced no difficulties myself using 32-bit Qt on 64-bit Windows with Visual Studio 2008.

Answer (score 0):

You can build 64 bit qt library using help at this link. 
http://qt-project.org/wiki/How_to_build_64bit_Qt_for_windows[here](http://qt-project.org/wiki/How_to_build_64bit_Qt_for_windows)

Answer (score -1):

If 64-bit applications (which may need a lot of memory resources, e.g. Compilers, IDEs and rendering programs) are available, you should always use 64-bit, in order to fully utilize your memory and optimize the performance.