# Advantages of a 64 bit system

Tags: c++, performance, architecture, 64-bit, cpu-architecture

From a developer perspective i am trying to understand , what is the selling point of a 64-bit system ?

I understand that more registers are at your disposal , more memory can be allocated to a process , but i cannot understand what makes a developer's life easier. Any examples ?

From a performance perspective are there any gains seen if a program is run on a 32bit vs 64 bit ?

Cheers!

EDIT : Thank you for all your replies. I see some conversations shooting towards end user experience , important as it may be.. I am looking more at any architectural benefits that you can squeeze out.

From what i understand , it looks like the optimizations are a lot at the compiler-assembler chain rather than a functionality which a programmer can call on ?

Comment: Probable duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3343812/64-bit-performance-advantages

Comment: Yep , checked that one... but all roads lead to more memory. Any thing else ?

Comment: Related: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Year_2038_problem

Comment: See my answer for some examples of optimizations a programmer can call on. I list two, one related to having a larger address space available, and the other related to being able to manipulate 64-bits of data at once.

Comment: "More registers" only applies to x86-64 versus x86 - most 32/64 bit architectures do not have this "feature" - they have the same number of registers but the registers are typically wider for 64-bits.

Comment: "more registers" also applies to ARM AArch64

Answer (score 9, accepted):

When you have 64-bits of address space to play with, you can adopt certain designs that would be very hard with less of an address space. For example, a friend recently pointed out to me that address space for thread stacks can get to be a problem with thousands of threads on a 32-bit system. But on a 64-bit system, this is no longer even remotely close to being a problem. This is the main direct benefit to developers that can affect how you write programs. And this is true regardless of how much actual memory the machine has.

Most programs I have seen converted to 64-bit have seen performance improvements because of the extra registers available.

Having 64-bit addresses can offset this performance improvement in some programs. The extra space pointers take up mean they take more cache, which leaves less space in your cache for other things. Also they take up more memory bus bandwidth when being transferred to and from main memory.

There is at least one project out there that proposes to recompile most programs in Linux in a sort of mixed-mode in which all the extra registers are used, but only 32-bit pointers are used. I'm interested in how this pans out because it removes the one performance disadvantage of 64-bit programs.

There is also a small (but important) subset of programs and algorithms that can make use of 64-bit registers. For example, most of the [SHA-3 candidates](http://ehash.iaik.tugraz.at/wiki/The_SHA-3_Zoo) are designed to take advantage of the ability to manipulate 64-bits of data at a time when doing bitwise operations.

Lastly, since the data paths inside the CPU are now 64-bits wide, this can also mean there is more bandwidth inside the CPU for moving things around. But I would expect this to be a benefit on 64-bit CPUs running in 32-bit mode as well.

Comment: I've also read about the extra consumption of the stack due to alignment issues at each function calls (despite the use of register the function still reserves space to save the data passed to it in case the registers are needed for something else).

Answer (score 1):

As you said, more memory can be a big advantage. For 32bit systems you'll be limited to processes max 4GB (or even 2 or 3, depending how annoying your OS is).

64bits is double the amount of bytes per instruction, so you have more bandwith internally. eg: faster everything.

see also:
http://lifehacker.com/5431284/the-lifehacker-guide-to-64+bit-vs-32+bit-operating-systems

Comment: By double meaning more than one instruction is processed ?

Comment: No, still one instruction (actually, that's not true, but now it's going to be a *very* long story :) but everything internally will work with 64 bits (8bytes) chunks, instead of 32 bits (4bytes) chunks. Just think of a 8 lane vs 4 lane highway.

Comment: Larger instruction sizes == more instruction cache misses?

Comment: @inverse: could be, but your cache will probably be larger anyway.

Comment: do the cache sizes change if you run a processor in 32-bit mode istdo 64-bit?

Answer (score 1):

When you run multiple processes e.g. debug session, compiler and other tools you will notice a big performance gain if you have lots of RAM in your system. I have 16GB RAM in my Win7 system and I will never go back to having less. Its a bit like when you start using dual monitors, one just isn't enough after that.

Comment: Isn't 16 GB kind of overkill? I multitask a lot, have three monitors and still my 4 GB memory + an SSD disk (if any swapping is ever needed) never produces any slowdowns whatsoever for me.

Comment: 16 GB might be overkill for some systems as of now (January 2011) but it won't continue to be so.

Comment: @monoceres: yeah, 640KB should be enough for everyone. (old Bill Gates quote, when 640KB was considered normal (yes, KB, a GB is a million times larger))

Comment: This isn't particular relevant, but I actually don't like dual monitors. I've used them and find them really annoying. But I also never make any of my windows on a regular monitor full screen. I would rather just have a much bigger monitor.

Comment: It will be used, be sure of that! If it will be of use is another matter entirely. Certainly database engines will be able to allow their generic caches to hold much more data than previously but even today the overhead is such that very little gain can be seen. It's not unlikely that office programs will require much more memory to execute in the semi-near future.

Answer (score 1):

A few Mac OS X specific answers (general ones are covered in other replies):

1) In 32 bit OSX, address space is mapped 4/4 (i.e. kernel gets the full 2^32 AND each app does), which requires flushing the TLB twice on each syscall. In 64 bit there's plenty of room to map the kernel and the application into different address ranges.

2) Objective-C programs use the new ABI/runtime on 64 bit x86 machines. This gets you C++ compatible exceptions, non-fragile instance variables, and some speedups.

Answer (score 0):

A 64-bit system has 64-bit memory addresses instead of 32-bit addresses, and so the maximum amount of memory available is 2<sup>64</sup> vs 2<sup>32</sup>.  This first quantity is roughly 10<sup>18</sup> bytes, compared to the 10<sup>9</sup> bytes you can have with the latter quantity.  Consequently, it's possible to have a lot more memory in a 64-bit system.

Comment: This isn't strictly true. Just because you don't have that much ram available doesn't mean the extra address space isn't useful. It allows you to space apart contiguous data structures that grow so you are less likely to have to move them (or simply run out of space if you can't move them).

Comment: Even on systems with few memory that additional address space may come in handy. One problem that went away with 64 bit is address space fragmentation. Some of my programs, dealing with large block of data of varying length had these problems when they ran in 32 bit mode. I was in the middle of implementing a rather complex memory management scheme, which got obsolete the day, 64 bit systems got commonplace.

Comment: @Omnifarious- Can you elaborate on this?  I don't quite follow what you're saying.

Comment: @templatetyedef - Say, for example, you have a bunch of arrays. You know that any one of the arrays could grow to be 800MB in size, but you also know that most of them will stay under 5MB. With 64 bits of address space you can have them all spaced 1G apart from eachother so they all could potentially grow. But the pages for the unused space will never be mapped, so you will never be using more than 1G or 2G of actual memory.

Comment: @Omnifarious- Ah, that makes perfect sense.  I didn't think of virtual memory.  I'll update my post to remove the inaccuracy.  Thanks for letting me know about that!

Answer (score 0):

Most desktop apps actually don't need to be 64 bits binaries, to the notable exception of image or video processing apps.  In contrast, server apps often do.

The best advantage of *running* on a 64Bits machine a is that your app will have more RAM space, so it won't get swapped away when other apps will need the RAM.  Yet 32 bit apps run on 64bits machine (luckily enough). I'm typing this on a 16GB Linux laptop with 2 DB (Oracle 11g and Mysql 6.0alpha), Windows in VirtualBox and a host of Java VMs, eclipse with Xmx=2GB...) and I couldn't cram all this on 4GB.  Yet I still prefer to run 32bits apps when they do not need large amount of memory space.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, I kept this a bit list style, and avoided not mentioning increased memory addressing and more which had already been mentioned.

*a)* You'll have double the amount of registers, actually giving you three times the amount of registers at you disposal. *b)* General purpose registers are increased from 32 to 64 bit, meaning processing of 64 bit integers (i.e.) will be faster. *c)* More efficient position independent code since data can now be referenced relative to the RIP register. *d)* [No-execute bit](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NX_bit) making the system more tolerant towards buffer overflows.