# Is there performance advantage to ARM64

Tags: performance, arm, 64-bit, arm64

Recently 64-bit ARM mobiles started appearing. But is there any practical advantage to building an application 64-bit? Specifically considering application that does not have much use for the increased virtual address space¹, but would waste some space due to increased pointer size.

So does ARM64 have any other advantages than the larger address that would actually warrant building such application 64bit?

Note: I've seen [64-bit Performance Advantages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3343812/64-bit-performance-advantages), but it only mentions x86-64 which does have other improvements besides extended virtual address space. I also recall that the situation is indeed specific to x86 and on some other platforms that went 64-bit like Sparc the usual approach was to only compile kernel and the applications that actually did use lot of memory as 64-bit and everything else as 32-bit.

---

¹<sub>The application is multi-platform and it still needs to be built for and run on devices with as little as 48MiB of memory. Does have some large data that it reads from external storage, but it never needs more than some megabytes of it at once.</sub>

Comment: There are some real AArch64 vs. AArch32 performance numbers [here](http://www.anandtech.com/show/7335/the-iphone-5s-review/4).

Comment: As with x86-64, AArch64 also comes with other improvements like doubling the number of registers, and so the comparison with x86-32-versus-64 seems reasonable.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I am not sure a general response can be given, but I can provide some examples of differences. There are of course additional differences added in version 8 of the ARM architecture, which apply regardless of target instruction set.

### Performance-positive additions in AArch64

- 32 General-purpose registers gives compilers more wiggle room.
- I/D cache synchronization mechanisms accessible from user mode (no system call needed).
- Load/Store-Pair instructions makes it possible to load 128-bits of data with one instruction, and still remain RISC-like.
- The removal of near-universal conditional execution makes more out-of-ordering possible.
- The change in layout of NEON registers (D0 is still lower half of Q0, but D1 is now lower half of Q1 rather than upper half of Q0) makes more out-of-ordering possible.
- 64-bit pointers make pointer tagging possible.
- CSEL enables all kind of crazy optimizations.

### Performance-negative changes in AArch64

- More registers *may* also mean higher pressure on the stack.
- Larger pointers mean larger memory footprint.
- Removal of near-universal conditional execution may cause higher pressure on branch predictor.
- Removal of load/store-multiple means more instructions needed for function entry/exit.

### Performance-relevant changes in ARMv8-A

- Load-Aquire/Store-Release semantics remove need for explicit memory barriers for basic synchronization operations.

I probably forgot lots of things, but those are some of the more obvious changes.

Comment: Why does change in NEON layout make more out-of-ordering possible?

Comment: @Nikolai: because ordering requirements between D-registers no longer require separate consideration from ordering requirements between Q-registers. In AArch32, two unrelated operations on Dx and Dx+1 could be forced to happen in program order, if they shared the same underlying Q register.

Comment: Not sure I understand your enthusiasm for the CSEL instruction. This does a small fraction of what the older conditional instructions could do. It really feels like a minimal effort on ARM's part to give us at least a small way to avoid some branches.

Comment: @BitBank: enthusiasm is because unlike the general-purpose-conditionals, CSEL does it without messing up out-of-ordering.

Comment: pointer tagging is also possible in 32 bits, although with less bits to tag than in 64 bits

Comment: One big advantage in practice of ARMv8 is the HW AES, CRC and SHA support, which is almost always present (albeit on RPi4 due to licensing price concerns): it would help TLS communication for both client and server sides. And encryption is likely to be a real bottleneck in most real usecases.