# effect of 32bit and 64 bit architecture on motherboard and CPU

Tags: architecture, operating-system

If a machine is running on a 32 bit operation system and now I am going to install a 64 bit operation system on that machine, what is the effect on the machine, is **MOTHER-BOARD** and **PROCESSOR** get affected but this,if yes then why and if not then why.....

is it's performance also depend on the RAM ?

What if for 64bit architecture  I use only 2 GB or 1 GB of RAM

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Processor, OS : 32bit, 64 bit](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1283797/processor-os-32bit-64-bit)

Comment: no it's not I already read that and My question's answer is not there

Comment: 32 bit and 64 bit are hardware specific. It defines what the bandwidth of bus. (32bit wide) registers size (32bits or 64 bits). It also tells the amount of data processor can process.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

32 bit or 64 bit defines how much binary the processor can process in one cpu cycle. Now what is this cpu cycle, exactly it is a small data structure that the cpu loads into memory to perform Arithmetic calculations.

I'll explain it in much better way. suppose you have two blanks, and you are allowed to put only one digit in one blank. further suppose you want to do calculation of 23 + 5...Now very simply you load 23 in first two blanks and 05 in other two blanks, now you use simple maths to solve it and put the answer again in two blanks i.e. 28. This shows if we have a limit of 2 blanks, still we can do arithmetic calculation of 1 numeric digit by just putting zero. This is how really cpu does calculations. (i.e. movzx and movsx) But you can't do a arithmetic of number which needs more than 2 blanks.

Similarly a 32 bit processor can process 16 bit and 32 bit instructions, but can't do 64 bit processing.

Operating systems are designed (i should use word kernel) for both x86 (32 bit) and x64 (64 bit) arch. it doesn't mean 32 bit kernel can't run on 64 bit processor. Exactly it can and theoretically possible too, but that is not much useful, profitable point of view. Running 32 bit Kernel on 64 bit processor is wasting of memory (literally saying, wasting of those blanks) and in more specific way we are also losing a much memory, And that is why only 64 bit kernels are specially designed for 64 bit processor.
Further Emulations or virtualization can also be used to run a 64 bit program on 32 bit processor. But that will slow down the speed of execution, why?
well, again suppose that two blanks question. now lets change the question. we have to do a arithmetic sum of 235 + 5. Ah! Now how to do this? well simple suppose 6 blanks.

```
0 2 3 5 : In first 4 blanks
    0 5 : In other 2 blanks
```

Now what processor does exactly is, sum up 35 + 05, i.e. 40 and then push carry flag, in this case we have no carry to push. Now processor come to 02 + carry, i.e. 2 hence the result is 240. As you it took more cpu cycles. hence it will slow down processing. One more thing these calculation need the help of emulation because processor still can't do such calculation so emulator tell him to do this in piecewise (same as what we have done above).

Comment: This is just belongs to CPU what about mother board and RAM in that ...

Comment: nothing happens to RAM. It all remains the same. And same for motherboard. Just whether the motherboard supports 64 bit processor or not.

Comment: Processor is what plays an important role here.

Comment: For one thing, addresses are 64-bit in 64-bit mode and so there's more data moved between the CPU and the memory in 64-bit mode than in 32-bit mode when that data contains addresses. Every subroutine call pushes the return address onto the stack and every subroutine return pops it back (on x86 CPUs).