# "32-bit OS", "32-bit processor": What exactly do these terms mean?

Tags: memory-management, operating-system, virtual-memory, cpu-architecture

What is the exact meaning of "32-bit OS", "32-bit processor"?

- Does it influence the size of address bus?
- Does it influence the number of virtual addresses that can be generated?
- How will it affect the register size means does the register size?
- What impact does it have on virtual memory/ memory management

I am a beginner in this area; please point me to some suitable docs if you have any.

Thanks.

Comment: multiple duplicates: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1283797/processor-os-32bit-64-bit http://stackoverflow.com/questions/132930/32-vs-64-bits-whats-the-big-deal http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1282206/what-is-the-actual-difference-between-64-bit-and-32-bit

Answer (score 8):

Why not start with the [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/32-bit) article?

Comment: If everyone did that, half of the collective reputation on SO wouldn't exist.

Answer (score 2):

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86#32-bit

or, if you really meant 64 bit,

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/64-bit